# I've installed Propel using PEAR on Windows... now where is propel-gen?

Tags: php, pear, propel

I've installed PEAR onto my Windows 7 PC using PEAR, as per:

http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/01-installation.html

Now, where can I find `propel-gen` so I can add it to my PATH?

Here's the files that have been installed, in the PEAR directory:

![Screen shot of C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\Propel][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUm8P.png)

Versions:

Phing 2.4.9
PHP 5.2.17
Xdebug 2.1.2

Has something gone wrong?

Comment: The screenshot doesn't work..

Comment: You have to click on the "1" hyperlink next to the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Propel requires the PHP XSL module; there didn't seem to be any indication of this when I tried to install it via PEAR.

After I reinstalled PHP with XSL, I tried to install Propel again via PEAR. This time it worked fine, and propel-gen.bat was added to my PHP directory (which is in my path settings).

Propel is, in a word, awesome - I'm glad I managed to get it to install. I think this framework will save me absolutely loads of time, and help me produce higher quality code.

Answer (score 1):

You should add:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\Propel\generator\bin
```

to your `PATH`, then you'll be able to execute `propel-gen.bat` (because you're on Windows).

Useful link: http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/01-installation#testing_propel_installation